# TLE for Spoj BTCK

Tags: c++, algorithm, backtracking

Hey there I have been working on this question recently but am unable to solve this question using backtracking.

> Question : You have to solve the following problem with Backtracking.
>   You're given a sequence of  10 positive integers n1  , n2 , n3 , ...
>   ,n9, n10 and a positive value K.
>
> To solve this problem you need to print a permutation a1  , a2 , a3 ,
>   ... ,a10 of the numbers {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} such that a1 * n1  + a2
>   * n2 + a3 *n3 + ...  + a10*n10 ≤ K
>
> Among all the permutations that solve the problem according to the
>   description above, print the lexicographically smallest.

[Link to question](http://www.spoj.com/problems/BTCK/)

My code goes as follows:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#define ll long long
#define forn(i,a,b) for(int i = a; i < b; i++)

using namespace std;

ll k;
bool solved = 0; // Tells if we have found a solution or not.
int ans[10];  // Will contain the final sequence of ai s
int arr[10];  // Contains the numbers provided in the question. For this example arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
bool vis[10]={false}; // Denotes if the value ai(see the question) has been used or not

void print();

bool solve(int n, ll sum, int movei)  // n = 10 , movei => which number we have to assign ai to.
{
    if(sum > k) {
            return false;   // Backtrack
    }
    if(movei == n)
    {
        return sum<=k;
    }
    forn(i,movei,n)
    {
        forn(j,0,10)
        {
            if(vis[j]) continue;
            ans[i]=j;
            vis[j]=1;
            if(solve(n, sum + arr[i]*j, movei+1)) return true; // If we found a solution return true
            vis[j]=0;
        }
    }
    return false; // We could not find any solution at all.
}

void print()
{
    forn(i,0,10)
    cout << ans[i] << " ";
}

int main()
{
    int t;         // Number of test cases
    //cin >> t;
    t = 1;
    while(t--)
    {
        forn(i,0,10) arr[i] = i+1; //cin >> arr[i];
        cin >> k;
        if(solve(10,0LL,0)) print();
        else cout << -1;
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

**Approach** : 
1) Check for all the paths
2) If you find a solution then that's gonna be the lexicographially smallest order and so return true, meaning solution is found else 
3) Continue to look for the solution. 
4) If you cannot find a solution in any path then return false, meaning solution cannot be found in which case I print -1.

How can I solve this question. I have been really working hard on this but can not think anything else.

Comment: What's with the useless defines and all the global variables? You should get a better learning resource; whatever you are using now is garbage.

Comment: *TLE for Spoj BTCK* -- Does that look like a title that is understood?  Why not state in full English what the topic of this thread is about?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I see you don't do competitive coding. But here what I'm trying to focus on is the algorithm and not he variables.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am new to stackoverflow Can you suggest me a better title? I would be happy if you do.

Comment: @Michelle -- *I see you don't do competitive coding* -- So I guess you don't learn how to write good code when doing "competitive coding".  Also the `ll` and `forn` macro stuff is horrible, seemingly boiler-plate code that is posted here many times.  As to the title, what is "TLE"?  What is "BTCK".  These are not industry standard acronyms.

Comment: @Michelle -- Also, what did you expect this `memset(ans, -1, sizeof(ans));` to do?  If it's to set all values in the array to -1, no.

Comment: I don't want to fight over all this stuff, what I am interested over here is the algorithm for this question, that's all.

Comment: @Michelle -- You posted code, code with the obvious issue I pointed out in the previous comment.  That in itself could be the problem, and not any algorithm.  Also, if it is an algorithm issue, why write any code whatsover if you don't know what the algorithm should be.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have used it many times and it has worked for me till now, what's wrong with this?

Comment: What does `memset` do?  It is not the same as `std::fill`, which is what you should be using.  The `memset` takes that *byte* sequence and populates each byte with that sequence.  That is far different than initializing elements of an `int` array with a value.  And saying that you've used it many times makes the point being made -- "competitive programming" does not teach how to write programs properly.  And last, this is the comment section -- you posted code, we can comment on it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for correcting me, you see that's why I uploaded my code.

Comment: you can easily solve this using next_permutation, this is basically asking you to implement that

Comment: @juvian thank you for the reply, I did not know about it before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @juvian and @PaulMcKenzie for your replies. Code is as follows,

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print(int a[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
}

int main()
{
    int test;
    cin >> test;
    int n[10], a[10], k;
    while(test--)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cin >> n[i];
        cin >> k;

        bool solved = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) a[i] = i;

        do
        {
            int k1 = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                k1 += n[i]*a[i];
            }
            if(k1 <= k)
            {
                solved = true;
                print(a, 10);
                break;
            }
        }while(next_permutation(a, a+10));

        if(!solved) cout << -1;
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```